# Same file value in 2 file inputs form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to populate a second file input with the selected file from the first.

I've looked into this and, for security reasons, it's not possible to get the full path from one file input - only the file name. This isn't of any help as the other file input won't be able to upload as it won't be able to find the file.

Example:

```
<input type="file" id="1" /> - User browse the file by clicking on this input
<input type="file" id="2" /> - This input gets the value from the other file input
```

The reason I want to do this is because I am building a web app in Wordpress that allows users to upload a photo to Facebook but I also what the same photo to be attached to the wp post. I don't want them to have to select the file for each input.

Is there any way to achieve this using PHP and jQuery?

Comment: I'm curious if this is, in fact, an XY problem. Why do you want a user to have the same file in two input fields?

Comment: because I am building a web app in wordpress, user can upload a photo to facebook but the same photo goes to a wp post. I don't want them to select twice the file for 2 file inputs

Comment: If I understand it correctly, why the 2 file inputs then? You just cant save file and then copy it to another location?

Comment: Could you show the php side of things? Why can't you use the same file once submitted? How are you pushing them across to wp and facebook?

Comment: I'm using 2 plugsin, one plugin is pubblishing using fb the other is creating a post from a front-end form.

Comment: @Down voter - why a down vote for a genuine question which clearly states of the secutiry reason as a demonstration that before to post in here i read lots? Cheers anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to security restrictions, you cannot programatically set the value of file input type fields, it is not possible.

Also, I don't see why you need to upload the same file twice? If you wish to save the same file in multiple locations, you can copy the first file into the second location too, isnt it ?

Please rephrase the question explaining why you want to upload the same file twice so a better answer can be given.

Comment: I know it's due to security, I did write it on my question too. I'm uploading one file to facebook and the other file to our server, they have 2 distinct forms and what I was tryong to do was to combine them both, all got well untill the input file issue

Comment: First upload the files to your server, and then you can programatically make the Facebook post using that same image. Exact code depends on what you are trying to do, and what API you are using - eg. its fairly easy to make a Facebook post with the uploaded image by passing the url using facebooks Graph API

Comment: Yes I'm using facebook Graph APi, i think I just got it wrong in terms of approach. Thanks for the help, this is the rigth solution

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are approaching this the wrong way. Modern browsers prevent you manipulating the value of file inputs for security reasons. What you are suggesting is not possible.

You should be uploading the file to one single location and the sending it to Facebook/WordPress once it is uploaded. If the method of submitting the photo to either must be via POST, then you can use cURL to send that file.

Here is an example: [Send a file via POST with cURL](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/)

Comment: yes you are correct, the previous answer already kind of let me think of doing this way, upload it to where i want first, then relocating the file. Thanks m